# Make Configuration changes to DbContext

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm using Code First.  I've created a DbContext but I'm not able to put the configuration settings in the constructor as I did in the regular Entity Framework.  Here's an example in regular EF6:

```
public AppsDbContext()
        : base("name=AppsDbContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
        this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
 }
```

I'm not able to do this in an EF-Core DbContext constructor.  What I noticed immediately is that I got this functionality from the System.Data.Entity namespace in EF, which apparently no longer exists.  I do not see a way I can add this namespace.  What am I missing? I'm guessing this is fairly trivial but I have not seen any examples in my search.

NOTE: I'm using EF Core 2.2

Comment: use ChangeTracker or Database properties of the context. 
`this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` 
`this.Database.AutoTransactionsEnabled = false;`
`this.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`

Comment: is this what you need? or I misunderstood the question?

Comment: That solves some of it.  I think the ValidateOnSaveEnabled may have been used in Database First. For example, if you made changes to the .edmx.  Here, I'm using Code First.  I still don't see anything on that particular setting or for proxycreationenabled.  Again, I'm not sure if we need to worry about this in EF Core.  Proxy creation may again be something that is leftover from the Database First construct.

Comment: no, you don't need to be worry about that, you have almost everything you need in ef core if you are ef6 user. for example, there is no proxycreationenabled in ef-core because, by default unlike ef6, ef-core is not using proxies at all. you can add this functionality if you need by installing separate packages ...

Comment: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading

Comment: Thanks again.  This is very helpful.

Comment: your welcome. good luck

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ChangeTracker` property instead of `Configuration` in EF-Core.

```cs
this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; 
this.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```